# Orthogonality of remaining non-intersecting basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ $\in \mathbb{C}^{4 \times 100}$ be matrices with null spaces $N(A)$ and $N(B)$ respectively. The dimensions of each null space is $96$ and I was able to find that they intersect in $92$ basis ($96+96-100=92$). Now, if they intersect in $92$ basis, then that leaves 4 basis in each null space (since the dimension of each null space is $96$) that don't intersect. Can the non-intersecting 4 bais in ($N(A)$) and the non-intersecting 4 basis($N(B)$) be orthogonal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  For example, consider the "standard" basis of unit vectors $e_i$ with $1$ in position $i$ and $0$ otherwise, with $N(A)$ spanned by $e_1, \ldots, e_{96}$ and $N(B)$ spanned by $e_5, \ldots, e_{100}$.  You could take
$$ A = \pmatrix{\ldots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\cr
                \ldots & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\cr
                \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\cr
                \ldots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\cr},\
    B =  \pmatrix{  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \ldots \cr
                    0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0 \ldots \cr
                     0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0 \ldots \cr
                     0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0 \ldots \cr} $$

Comment: Thank you. I understand how your example will lead to orthogonal non-intersecting basis. Can we say that about any basis and not just the standard one. Also, how can I find these orthogonal non-intersecting basis?. I know how to find the null space basis as well as the intersection, but don't know how to find the non-intersecting basis.